# jQuery, php and FancyBox

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I recently installed fancybox to my website, I searched here and at google for this solution but had no good stuff to read.

The problem is, I have a php that generates an array and transform it to json_encode, the code is bellow.

```
$array = ("http://exemplo.com/image1.jpg","http://exemplo.com/image2.jpg");
return json_encode($array);
```

At my javascript, I have this situation called by an ID:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: Application.build_url("lista/busca-fotos/"),
   data: "id="+$id,
   success: function(data){
    $.fancybox([data], {
        'padding' : 0,
        'transitionIn' : 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type' : 'image',
        'changeFade': 0
    });                
   }
  });
```

But, it won't work, I think that I should use parseJSON, but when I do it, the object resultant is null, How can I use this option to show a gallery with images?

It should be like this, this is the online example that works, my data must be replace inside the fancybox([data],...:

```
    $("#manual2").click(function() {
    $.fancybox([
        'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4044/4286199901_33844563eb.jpg',
        'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
        {
            'href'  : 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4213562882_851e92f326.jpg',
            'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
        }
    ], {
        'padding'           : 0,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'image',
        'changeFade'        : 0
    });
});
```

Thanks and best regard's, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: what exaclty does not work? Do you get an error message? Is the content type of the page your loading with AJAX explicitly set to "application/json"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to create an array does not appear to be syntactically correct.
The proper way to initialize an array is like this:

```
$myArray = array(("item1","item2", "item3", "etc."));
```

Also, **return** won't output anything to the client, you should use **echo** instead.

Your code snippet should look like this:

```
$array = array(("http://exemplo.com/image1.jpg","http://exemplo.com/image2.jpg");
echo json_encode($array);
```